# Issue with moving list items with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to figure this out for about a day, but I haven't been making too much progress. I want to have two lists, and move list items between them by double-clicking. I can get it to work if I have one event be "click", and the other "dblclick", but that's not what I want. If I attach "dblclick" events in both methods, the list items won't move and will just reorder themselves in the current list. Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates my problem. I currently have it setup so one event is "click" and the other is "dblclick". If you change the parameter in the live function to "click" so it matches the other handler you'll see the issue I've been having.

**HTML**

```
<div id="orig">
<ul>
    <li class="original">one</li>
    <li class="original">two</li>
    <li class="original">three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="moved">
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#orig {
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#moved {
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".original").click(function(){
        this.className = "moved";
        $("#moved ul").append(this);
    });

    $(".moved").live("dblclick", function() { 
        this.className = "original";
        $("#orig ul").append(this);
    });

});
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmnAm/4/)

Comment: I believe you may have left out your code. jsFiddle may not be around for as long as Stack Overflow..

Comment: Sorry about that. This is my first time posting and I'm not familiar with the interface and didn't see any way to preview what I'm posting.

Comment: I've done it for you. There is a preview of your question before you submit it, right below where you create it.

Comment: I was just looking for something like this for use in a form, and found this solution, which looks awesome but I have not tried it yet: http://www.jquery-az.com/a-jquery-multi-select-list-view-plug-in-with-six-options/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, `live` is already deprecated:

```
$("#orig").on("dblclick", "li", function() {
    $("#moved ul").append(this);
});

$("#moved").on("dblclick", "li", function() {
    $("#orig ul").append(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmnAm/6/

Plus you can also make it even shorter if you set a class to your `div` containers:

```
$container = $('.container').on('dblclick', 'li', function(e) {
    $container.not(e.delegateTarget).find('ul').append(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmnAm/7/

Comment: I updated the jQuery to 1.9.1 and used your first code sample. It works wonderfully. Thanks! I was using 1.8.3 because I was having an issue with @Ajax.ActionLink(), but I can now start looking into that.

Answer (score -1):

When you apply your eventhandlers to your listitems, they stay onto those elements the whole time. When you click an item on the left item, then click that same item on the right list, it'll still be the same item, with the same eventhandler you clicked on, so it'll still be moved to the right one, which it's already in.

You'll probably have to remove the original handler from the item you just clicked, and attach the other one to the item.